# funcList Visual Studio Code regex for custom language

Tags: vscode-extensions, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to get the `funcList` visual studio code extension plugin to work with a proprietary language that I use and I'm having a problem getting the regex to work. The plugin documentation can be found here: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qrti.funclist and describes creating a `settings.json` file inside the `.vscode` folder of your project. My problems arise when trying to modify the `regex` expressions for the `funcList.nativeFilter` and `funcList.displayFilter` configuration values. Here is my current `settings.json` file:

```
{
    "funcList.nativeFilter": "/(?:^|\\s)Function\\s+\\w+\\(/mg",
    "funcList.displayFilter": "/\\s*Function\\s+(.*)/1",
    "funcList.sortList": 1,
    "funcList.doubleSpacing": false
}
```

I believe the main problem is the part of `\\w+` in the `nativeFilter` property. This seems to only match on characters/numbers but not any special characters. Here is a snippet of a piece of code that I would like to work with this Function List:

```
Function Do.Something(paramOne, paramTwo)
    '...
End Function


Method Do.Something_Else(paramOne, paramTwo)
    '...
End Function
```

Ideally, the `nativeFilter` would capture `Function Do.Something(paramOne, paramTwo)` .. until `End Function` and then the `displayFilter` would only capture the first line (ie. `Do.Something(paramOne, paramTwo)`)

**Note**: according to the docs, `nativeFilter` does not allow regex groups, but `displayFilter` allows groups 0-9.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use this for javascript and the funcList extension.  It is similar to what you are trying to do:

```
// so that "function someName(arg1, arg2) is captured

  "funcList.nativeFilter": "/^[a-z]+\\s+\\w+\\s*\\(.*\\)/mgi",

// now display  "someName(arg1, arg2)"

  "funcList.displayFilter": "/\\S* +(\\w+\\s*\\(.*\\))/1",
```

You obviously have capital letters, periods and underscores to worry about but hopefully this helps you to some degree.  [I see I did not need to actually put the `function` keyword in to make it work...]

[EDIT]  Try this, it seems to work:

```
 "funcList.nativeFilter": "/^Function \\w+.\\w+\\(.*\\)?/mg",

 "funcList.displayFilter": "/\\S* +(\\w+.\\w+\\(.*\\))/1",
```

You just needed the . as it is not included in \w

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be working for my needs:

```
{
    "funcList.nativeFilter": "/^(Function|Method|Macro)\\s+[a-zA-Z0-9.+(){}\\/\\\\[\\],_\\-=:;!@#$%^&*|,.<>? ]*\\).*$/mg",
    "funcList.displayFilter": "/\\s*((Function|Method|Macro)\\s+[a-zA-Z0-9.+(){}\\/\\\\[\\],_\\-=:;!@#$%^&*|,.<>? ]+)/1"
}
```

With this plugin, you need to capture the entire line in order to get the navigation to work when clicking on a function list.

Comment: Did you try my edited version?  Just add the Method and Macro like you have to the beginning of the nativeFilter (Function|Method|Macro)and it works just fine.  It is far simpler than yours.  And can you give an example where navigation doesn't work where the nativeFilter stops after the parameter list and navigation does not work.  And it is my impression that the displayFilter is starting with the nativeFilter result so no need to repeat the (Function|Method|Macro) stuff at the beginning, but I may be wrong about that.